# Sticky button flickering while scrolling in iOS device

Tags: ios, css, button, responsive-design, device

We have fixed the button on bottom of page in RWD mobile using `position: fixed`. Working fine in Android device, but flickering in iOS device while scrolling. We tried the following to the element fixed. None of them worked. Any solution for this issue?

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the fixed element from the container that has -webkit-overflow-scrolling and put that somewhere else.